# How to create a power automate on a Sharepoint List when a new item contains a certain value

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate, microsoft-teams, microsoft-forms

I have a SharePoint list fed from MS Forms and I want to create a Power Automate alert when a specific response is received to one of the survey questions. Thinking an MS Teams notification.

At the moment I can see flows that are good for general alerts on a new item or change of item like we use to do in SP Designer, but not one for a flow based on a column specific value.

It seems like this should be an OOTB flow and hoping someone can direct me to it.

Cheers

Comment: Are you adding MS forms data into SharePoint using Power Automate?If yes, you can add a condition based on form response in the same flow to send notification (email or anything else you want)

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. I have added the condition and notification to my original Flow.

Comment: Great, I am glad that this approach helped you. I have written it as an answer below. Please accept it as an answer so that it will help others with same question to find the correct answer easily and also it will not be shown under "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to create a new workflow on SharePoint list for this.

As you are adding MS forms data into SharePoint using Power Automate, you can add a condition based on form response (as per your requirements) in the same flow.

And when condition meets you can send notification to users (either email or Teams notification or push notification or anything else you want)

Answer (score 0):

In Flow, or Power Automate, we have triggers similar to what you have used in workflow, and more powerful. The following one is a trigger for you, it starts the flow when a new response is submitted to the form you linked to.

[image]

Then you can add an if condition for selecting process based on the response
[image]

And there are a bunch of teams Actions for you to choose.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Jerry. I have added the condition and notification trigger to the initial FLOW exporting from Forms to the SharePoint List. I hadn't even considered this as I would always have run a separate worklow of the list if using SPD. Tested and works.

Comment: @Scott. Glad to hear you get it wok. Please accept the reply as answer if it keeps working without any trouble. That will help other community members with similar question.